# How to join two tables in mysql with matching data and group in array

Tags: mysql

I need to join two tables (products and orders) in mysql with a matching data (order id) and different data (products ids) that should be in a array.

I tried with a simple JOIN but data are not being grouped. Does anyone can give me a light?

```
SELECT Order.id, Order.userId, Product.id AS productsIds
FROM Orders AS Order
JOIN Products AS Product
ON Order.id = Product.orderId
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 1,
    "productsIds": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 1,
    "productsIds": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 1,
    "productsIds": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "userId": 2,
    "productsIds": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "userId": 3,
    "productsIds": 3
  }
]
```

**Expected:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 1,
    "productsIds": [2, 5, 6]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "userId": 2,
    "productsIds": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "userId": 3,
    "productsIds": 3
  }
]
```

Comment: Read up on GROUP BY clauses in SQL and the GROUP_CONCAT() function. That should get you started.

Comment: *Result:* Shown query cannot produce shown result. The query returns plain rowset whereas shown output is obviously JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **GROUP BY** clause and **GROUP_CONCAT** in select statement, will give the expected result.

Following is the query.

```
SELECT Order.id, Order.userId, GROUP_CONCAT(Product.id) AS productsIds FROM Orders AS Order JOIN Products AS Product ON Order.id = Product.orderId GROUP BY Order.id, Order.userId ;
```